# Google Charts Problems when Working with AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, google-visualization

I'm creating a data visualization page for an IoT device using Google Charts. Apparently somethings wrong (because i cant see the chart) but there's no error message.

Here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="chart" style="width:700px; height:300px;"></div> 
</body>

<script>

    google.charts.load('visualization', { packages: ['corechart'] });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawLineChart);

    function drawLineChart() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/chart/db.php",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                data.addColumn('Time Stamp', 'Temperature');    




                 $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                   data.addRow([value.Date, value.Data]);
                });
                // Set chart Options.
                var options = {
                    title: 'Temperature Sensor',
                    curveType: 'function',
                    legend: { position: 'bottom', textStyle: { color: '#555', fontSize: 14} }  
                };




                var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
                chart.draw(data, options);     
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Got an Error');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</html>
```

This is the PHP:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "dexiva";
    $mysqli = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname) or die($mysqli->error);

    //query to get data from the table
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE device_fk = 1 ";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

    // Array declaration
    $date = array();
    $data = array();

    // This is the code that works
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        $temp = json_decode($row['ddata'],true);

        $date[] = array('Date' => $row['datetime']);
        $data[] = array('Date' => $row['datetime'],'Data' => $temp['Data']); 
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

This is how the php code returns the information:

```
[{"Date":"2019-12-18 01:39:36","Data":25},{"Date":"2019-12-18 01:39:42","Data":25},{"Date":"2019-12-18 01:39:46","Data":25},{"Date":"2019-12-18 01:39:49","Data":25},{"Date":"2019-12-18 01:39:52","Data":25},{"Date":"2019-12-18 01:39:56","Data":25},{"Date":"2019-12-18 01:39:59","Data":25},{"Date":"2019-12-18 01:40:02","Data":25},{"Date":"2019-12-18 01:40:06","Data":25},{"Date":"2019-12-18 01:40:09","Data":25},{"Date":"2019-12-18 01:40:12","Data":25},{"Date":"2019-12-18 01:40:16","Data":25},{"Date":"2019-12-18 01:40:19","Data":25},{"Date":"2019-12-18 01:40:21","Data":25},{"Date":"2019-12-18 01:40:24","Data":25},{"Date":"2019-12-18 01:40:27","Data":25},{"Date":"2019-12-18 01:40:31","Data":25},{"Date":"2019-12-18 01:40:34","Data":25},{"Date":"2019-12-18 01:40:36","Data":25},{"Date":"2019-12-18 01:40:39","Data":25},{"Date":"2019-12-18 01:40:43","Data":25},{"Date":"2019-12-18 01:40:45","Data":25},{"Date":"2019-12-18 01:40:47","Data":25},{"Date":"2019-12-18 01:40:49","Data":25}]
```

Comment: From what little there is to tell from your code I assume it has to do with you overwriting the `data` variable in the beginning of the `success` callback.

Comment: Yeah, I fixed that and do a litter change on the AJAX and it is working perfectly now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more research I found that on of the problems was that the `<body>` tag needs to be after the script and not before. Like Emiel Zuurbier said, $data variable was being overwritten. After that no further php code modification is needed. Here is how the HTML structure needs to look like.

````html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
    // Visualization API with the 'corechart' package.
    google.charts.load('visualization', { packages: ['corechart'] });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawLineChart);

    function drawLineChart() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/chart/db.php",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                var arr = [['Time Stamp', 'Temperature']];    // Define an array and assign columns for the chart.

                // Loop through each data and populate the array.
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    arr.push([value.Date, value.Data.TEMP]);
                });

                // Set chart Options.
                var options = {
                    title: 'Temperature',
                    curveType: 'function',
                    legend: { position: 'bottom', textStyle: { color: '#555', fontSize: 14} }  // You can position the legend on 'top' or at the 'bottom'.
                };

                // Create DataTable and add the array to it.
                var figures = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arr)

                // Define the chart type (LineChart) and the container (a DIV in our case).
                var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
                chart.draw(figures, options);      // Draw the chart with Options.
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Got an Error');
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<body>
    <div id="chart" style="width:700px; height:300px;"></div> 
</body>
</html>```
````